# Finding largest numbers that go into target leaving smallest remainder

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to be able to find the smallest number that goes into the target.

For example:

```
target = 100
vals = [57, 71, 87, 97, 99, 101, 103, 113, 114, 115, 128, 129, 131, 137]

from itertools import combinations

def subsets_with_sum(lst, target, with_replacement=False):

    x = 0 if with_replacement else 1
    def _a(idx, l, r, t):
        if t == sum(l): r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            _a(u + x, l + [lst[u]], r, t)
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target)
```

If I were to input:

```
subsets_with_sum(vals, 270, False)
```

into the shell, I would output:

```
[[57, 99, 114]]
```

However, if I were to input:

```
subsets_with_sum(vals, 239, False)
```

into the shell, I would output:

```
[]
```

Instead, I would like to output the largest numbers that go into the target:
`[137, 101]` leaving remainder 1.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Instead of the lines:

```
        if t == sum(l): r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): return
```

You would want to store the best possible result, something like the following:

```
better = lambda x, y: x if sum (x) > sum (y) else y

def subsets_with_sum(lst, target, with_replacement=False):

    x = 0 if with_replacement else 1
    def _a(idx, l, r, t):
        if t >= sum(l):
            r = better (r, l)
            for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
                r = better (r, _a(u + x, l + [lst[u]], r, t))
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target)
```

---

That said, if the values are small integers, your problem (with and without replacements) is a case of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in_advance_algorithm), and there is an asymptotically faster solution using dynamic programming (see the link).

Comment: Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: Could you tell me if this is faster or the method provided by Ankush below is faster? Or show me how I can work it out?

Comment: @SyedArafatQureshi 1. To see which one is faster, you can run both on the same large input.

Comment: @SyedArafatQureshi 2. Both approaches are too slow anyway since they try all possible combinations of summands. If you need speed, please read the Wikipedia link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get all possible combination of summation possible (using recursion) and then find the summation which is closest to the target

```
target = 239
vals = [57, 71, 87, 97, 99, 101, 103, 113, 114, 115, 128, 129, 131, 137]

# recursive function to get all possible summations
# return a dict whose keys are the summation values 
# and values are list of elements that makes up that summation
def get_all_poss_sums(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return {0: []}
    else:
        i = l.pop()
        temp_sums = get_all_poss_sums(l)
        sums = {}
        for s in temp_sums:
            sums[s] = temp_sums[s]
            sums[s + i] = temp_sums[s] + [i]
        return sums

# get all possible summation
all_poss_sums = get_all_poss_sums(vals)

# find the summation closest to target
for s in sorted(all_poss_sums.keys(), reverse=True):
    if s <= target:
        print all_poss_sums[s] #outputs [101, 137]
        break
```

Comment: How can I find if this is faster or the method above?

Comment: Also, you forgot the brackets on print - using Python 3 :)